# iOS8 -- Insert Login page between (not in front of) Views (tabbed application)

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, ios8, xcode6

I am writing an application with 5 tabbed view (using storyboard), but I am stuck with how to insert login page. I have read through many threads, but I don't think any of them solves my problem. Here is the issue

1. The first view is visible for both login users and guests. (Default view when user launch application)
2. When guests try to view other four tabs, they are prompted to a login page (view)
3. If guest cancel logging in, guest will come back to first view. If guest login, they will go to whatever view he clicked before.

I have been thinking about this, it looks like I "insert" an view between tabbed view switching; and This view is "smart" enough to know whether should proceed to the view user wants (loggin case) or come back to where user started ( cancel cases). Any thoughts on this?

Best,
Bin

Comment: Just put the login view in the viewDidAppear method of each tab bar view and then prompt them to sign in if not already

Comment: I thought about this, but it won't work because if I cancel login, I will not go back to my first view.

Comment: sure you can. You have to remember. We are in control of the app. You can programmatically switch tab bars. So put it in view did appear and have a button that performs the task to go back to tab #1 of they don't want to sign in like so MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  [appDelegate SwitchToTab:index]

Comment: Hi Soulshined, thanks for your answer. I tried both your way and gabuh's way. They both work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol

Then you could verify if the user is logged or not and present the login page modally. And if the user cancels the logging, just dismiss the presented view controller.

Comment: Hi gabuh, I just tried your suggestion. I put this method in my first tab view. If user is not logged in, every time I click on the tab bar, log in page will come up, even I click on my first tab view. Since my first view is supposed to be visible for both logged in users and guest, I don't really want to ask guest to sign in when the click on the first item (first view) of tab bar.

Comment: I also find that when I present my login page modally and dismiss the page later, it won't come back to my first view, it will continue to the next tab view.

Comment: Inside that method you will know where you are, and where are you going, so you could decide if present or not the login if you are on your first view. And you could change the selected tab programatically, so you could go to the view you want.